# How to load elements of clearcase view to local file system

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm looking out for `cleartool` command which retrieves all the elments(files) of the given path (`myvob\projects\projectname`) and stores them in the local file system.
This makes me avoid creating the view again with the same config spec just to see the contents of the view and not to perform any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, creating a snapshot view with a specif load rule just for that path would be the more efficient way to do it.

If you don't want to create a view *each time* you need such a file consultation, I would still recommend to create a *dynamic* view (but only once), with a config spec you can change at will.
Since it is a dynamic view, you will be able to tweak that config spec and see the files instantly. Once you have the right versions, you can copy them wherever you want on your disk.